# VBA IE automation: loop for opening multiple tabs with identical names and URLs and performing same action in them

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

Suppose I have a list of identical URLs in spreadsheet column.

I navigate to the URL manually, then I want my macro to open every URL in separate IE tab and also click a specific button in it.

I use custom function `FindIEObject` to grab browser window by name or URL.The problem is that obviously each tab will have the same name and URL, so I need to find another way to differentiate between them and set each one as current IE object. My first thought was to assign a dummy name or a number to each tab as it gets created. I suppose this part should go somewhere after `IE.Navigate Cell.Value` in the loop.

Here is my code, currently opening all the tabs, but clicking the element only in the first one:

```
Private page_title As String
Public IE As InternetExplorerMedium

Sub intercept()

FindIEObject ("Allegro")

For Each Cell In Columns("A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlConstants)
    IE.Navigate Cell.Value, CLng(2049) ' open URL in new tab
    'Call MyWait
        For Each element In IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("img")
            If element.GetAttribute("src") = "https://assets.allegrostatic.com/opbox/allegro.pl/homepage/Main%20page%20-%20new_SG_categories%20-%20icons/c4c8134ad8ae75c9d1070e7bee8cbeea.svg" Then
               element.Click
               Exit For
            End If
        Next element
Next Cell

End Sub

Sub MyWait()

Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
End Sub

Public Function FindIEObject(target As String) As InternetExplorerMedium
        marker = 0
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
        For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
            page_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
            page_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title
            If page_title Like target & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
                Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
                marker = 1
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    If marker = 0 Then
        MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
    Else
        MsgBox ("A matching webpage was found")
    End If

    End Function
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Try updating the title with an index so you can keep track. Something like: `IE.Document.Title = IE.Document.Title & "1"` Why does this need to happen in separate tabs? Can't you just keep making new ones and kill the old one?

Comment: Thanks Ryan, but IE is always the first tab until I tell it otherwise.